# Do champions go on sale in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I started playing League of Legends recently, and I was thinking of buying one of the champions with the IP I have so far (a bit more than 3k).

My questions is: do the prices of champions change? If so, when?

I notice that some sell for 6k while Ashe - for instance - sells for around 500. Should I just buy all the low-price ones and wait until the expensive ones get cheaper, or should I save up until I get one of the better champions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While champions *do* sometimes get put on sale, the blue essence prices required to purchase them are not lowered, only the Riot Point costs are.

Do note, however, that in addition to a, perhaps quite lengthy, wait for the champion you're looking for, you will also have to pay real money (in Riot Points) to even take advantage of it.

The mechanic Riot has introduced for reducing champion blue essence costs over time is as follows:

- Champions are released costing 7800 blue essence. After one week, this is reduced to 6300.
- With each new champion released, the oldest 6300 blue essence champion is reduced in cost to 4800.
- Every third champion release will *also* mark the reduction of an older champion by one price tier (4800 -> 3150, or 3150 -> 1350).

Riot releases the schedule of which champions are up for price reduction in advance, so there should be few surprises on that front (though now that their time between champ releases has doubled, it'll be much longer between price reductions).

Comment: As an update, Riot has recently lowered the IP prices on a few champions.  It's still a very rare occurrence.

Comment: Here is the post about it : http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/champion-pricing-reduction-plan

Comment: This is no longer true.

Comment: @Aeronth It's also 2 years old. ;) I'll update it.

Comment: still up-to-date?

Answer (score 7):

Champions do get cheaper. Here is how the system works:

- When a champion is new it is 7800 blue essence.
- After one week it is reduced to 6300.
- After a new champion the oldest champion that still costs 6300 blue essence gets reduced to 4800.
- Then, after each third release, an already 4800 blue essence champ or lower gets reduced to another tier.  (3150, 1350, or 450 B.E.)

Comment: This is how it works now, it has been changed a few months ago I think.

Answer (score 1):

IP prices of champions do not change. Their RP cost may go on sale at times.

If you are looking for ways to get champions on the cheap, I reccommend grabbing the bundles. For what you pay, you get a lot of champions for what would normally take you a long time to gather the IP for or cost a lot of money individually to buy. This would still cost real money for you though.